# Yahoo YUI2 datatable checkboxes submitting

Tags: javascript, yui, checkbox

I have this datatable an YUI datatable inside a dialog. The datatable has only 2 columns where only one is editable with `formatter: "checkbox"`. I'm wondering is there any way to collect only the changed data or how should I get all the data to submit it with AJAX request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an sample how to listen to the checkbox click event and select the row of the datatable. You should change the code of selecting the row by a ajax query to post your data changed.

```
myDataTable.subscribe("checkboxClickEvent", function (oArgs) {
            var elCheckbox = oArgs.target;
            var oRecord = this.getRecord(elCheckbox);

            if (elCheckbox.checked) {
                myDataTable.selectRow(oRecord);
            } else {
                myDataTable.unselectRow(oRecord);
            };
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But how can I submit them at once using the dialog widget ?

Answer (score 0):

In a change event listener for the check box (the click event listener), you could add the obtained records into a (global) array by using something similar to

```
changedArray.push(oRecord);
```

And when you want to send it, send changedArray. You could also prevent multiple adds.

```
if (!changedArray[oRecord.keyElement]) {
    changedArray.push(oRecord);
    changedArray[oRecord.keyElement] = true;
}
```